# ScrollView ignores child's layout_height

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

Got a LinearLayout containing a textview and an edittext. The LinearLayout is inside a ScrollView.

The ScrollView is inside another view hierarchy (part of a Work Space layout, like the Android Homescreen kinda), but this fills parent, both height and width (I set fill color different to check this).

With attributes of fill_parent for layout_height and layout_width on the LinearLayout though, it's only filling the parent width-ways, not height. Setting the height to fixed also doesn't work/ no effect. It's as if it's stuck on wrap_content, in effect.

In actuality, checking the hierarchy viewer, it's set to match_parent. Oddly, the weightsum of the LL is set to -1 (in the Hierarchy Viewer); the weightsum is not explicitly set.

If there's any further info I can supply to figure out why it's not honouring the layout_height attribute, let me know :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could add your xml layout.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ScrollView has an infinite height (or height determined by the needs of its child), so `layout_height="fill_parent"` is not meaningful for views inside it.

**Edit** - Romain Guy has an [interesting article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141113211725/http://www.curious-creature.org:80/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/) about this, and the solution is indeed to use `fillViewport`.

Try setting it on the ScrollView itself in xml: `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: Perfect thanks :] Cheers for the link too, very interesting read :}

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bit of a troublesome layout to me (a mess :P)

But what I would say is play with the fillViewPort attribute, which will make the ScrollView take up the height available to it [Android fillViewPort Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport)

If you however want something similar to home screen I found out a way to force the view to take that exact height (See the stock Android news app, Tweetdeck or Admob [beta] for the sliding effect I'm referring to).

If this is the case let me know and I'll bung up some source code to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I've got a view which emulates the homescreen already :) The layout's not that complicated, perhaps I didn't explain so well :P Thanks for the answer :]